# Duplicate a image variable GD library

Tags: php, gd

What is the easiest way to duplicate an image variable in PHP.

Normally you can simply do `$varnew = $varold`.

But with a GD library variable if I did the above and then edited $varnew then $varold would be effected too.

Obviously one way would be to reopen the file or to make a new image and copy it into it. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your try didn't work is because the variable only stores a handle (a memory pointer) to the GD image. Both `$varnew` and `$varold` will still store the same pointer, thus pointing to the exact same image in memory. You have to use [imagecopy](http://php.net/imagecopy) or, maybe worse, open the image from file again.

Answer (score 3):

Use This:

```
function cloneImg($img){
    //get dimensions
    $w = imagesx($img);
    $h = imagesy($img);
     //copy process
    $copy = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    imagecopy($copy, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h);

    return $copy;

  }
```

Comment: This turned the transparent parts of my png image to opaque black.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [imagecopy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php)