# How to undo image_filter from php gd?

Tags: php-gd

I am using the following code.

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng('1.png');
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -40);
....
imagedestroy($im);
```

Now, I have to create the image again to apply different filter.

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng('1.png');
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, 100,50,0);
....
imagedestroy($im);
```

Do i need to destroy and create that image every time to apply a new effect?
Or can we use it by removing the previous filter?

Comment: You will have to "clone" the GD resource before applying the filter, maybe something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32363287/179545